# What is wrong with my HTML-Javascript-connection?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some trouble with my website:
When the website finished loading in the browser (onload) it should trigger a JavaScript Function called divTimeout1() in an external JavaScript-File

This is my code:

```
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
<body onload="divTimeout1()">
[...]
```

and my javascript.js file:

```
function divTimeout1() {
  var div = document.getElementById("info_pic");
  var opacity = div.style.opacity;
  var inter = setInterval( function f (div, opacity) {
    if (parseInt(opacity) > 0) {
      div.style.opacity = (parseInt(div.opacity)-1) + "%" 
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(inter)   
    }
  }, 10)
}
```

Is my JavaScript-code wrong? Or did I do something wrong with the "embedding" of the Script?

Thanks for your advice in advance...

Comment: Open developers console and do some debugging.

Comment: If you put the script directly in the html file does it work?  If yes, check the path of your js file.  If no, debug your function.

Comment: there is some error in your function that's causing problem

Comment: Can you create a demo using jsbin.com or jsfiddle?

Comment: i corrected the errors accorting to jslint ...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m54cyf09/     this should be an example for my problem

Comment: Will you be ok with jquery solution?

Comment: @Fabian Schneider, remember that the javascript you have in your example is already called on the window.load event.  Here's an [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/m54cyf09/1/).  Maybe you could update your question to include your updated html/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those situation, you should always look at the browser's console to see what is the error message (if there's any).

In your particular case, you should take your javascript outside the html and trace from there to see what is going on inside the `divTimeout1` function.

```
window.onload = function() {
  divTimeout1();
}
```

If you are using JQuery, you should consider using the [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) instead to make sure the whole html is loaded before trigerring your function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  divTimeout1();
})
```

Most modern browser have great debugging tools to trace the javascript execution.  In chrome, you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> and then put a break point on the line you want to break in.

Comment: what do u mean by "take the javascript outside the html.?" there is no difference

Comment: @Alex The smurf means to remove the `onload` attribute from the `body` start tag. Not sure why he thinks it would help any though.

Comment: Exactly... triggering function from html event is (almost) the same thing but it's easier to trace what's going on in the debugger when hook them directly in javascript.

Comment: I put the code from the HTML into the JS-file like you told me... and added a line to it : alert("test"); for testing if the script is loaded...

Comment: but no action took place... and the browser console didn't tell me about a not loaded file...

Comment: Was your alert the first line called in `window.onload`?  If so, this mean that this code doesn't get called.  If so, there's probably an error inside one of you JS file (but the console would have raise a message about it) or it may be because your working on a cached version of your page. Empty your browser cache and reload your page to see if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a half-baked animation which can be easily handled by CSS transitions, avoiding going to all the trouble of having to write JS which seems to be giving you trouble. Try something along these lines:

```css
#info_pic            { transition: opacity 1s; opacity: 0; } 
#info_pic.transition { opacity: 1; }
```

```
function startTransition() {
    document.getElementById('info_pic').className = 'transition';
}

document.body.onload = startTransition;
```

There are too many problems in your original code to go into here. But I doubt if that's relevant since using CSS transitions is so much cleaner.